# Is it possible to get user's PUID or NetId using AAD Graph API or the SDK

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using the Azure Active Directory Graph API version 1.6 and need to get the User's PUID property and it doesn't seem to be there in the contract in the latest SDK or in the response of the AAD Graph REST Api.

Looked at this document and cannot find PUID:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Is there any other API that I can use to get the user's PUID when I have the User's ObjectId?

I can get the PUID from the user's claims but I need to get it using the API.